# `lsblk` can list a partition, but `vgs` do not list the VolGroup

Tags: linux, disk

`lsblk` can list a partition, but `vgs` do not list:

[image]

The sda is added by me, the `vgs` do not list the VolGroups of `sda2`?

How can I mount the `sda2` to the sdb's `/mnt`?

Comment: It lists *the single* VG.

Comment: it do not list the added disk's VG, alright?

Comment: Yes, it did. That drive has a single VG, called "VolGroup".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That output looks pretty normal, so I think you might just be misunderstanding what it is saying...

Your disk `sdb` is split into 3 partitions and none of them is using LVM, but they have filesystems directly on them and they're already mounted on your machine. `/dev/sdb1` mounted as `/home`, `/dev/sdb2` is the root filesystem and `/dev/sdb3` mounted under `/web`.

Your disk `sda` has two partitions. The first partition has 500MB and is currently not mounted. (I imagine it was formatted for `/boot`, but anyways, it's not currently mounted.)

The second partition of `sda`, which would be `/dev/sda2` is in an LVM volume group called VolGroup. That's what `vgs` and `pvs` is listing!

You can't mount `/dev/sda2` directly, since it's a volume group, so you need to mount the logical volumes from there...

The output of `lsblk` also gives you a hint of what the volumes are, they are called `lv_root` (which I imagine is a root filesystem), `lv_home` (for the home directories) and `lv_swap` (for the swap partition.)

So looks like `sda` has another installation of Linux, which is not the one you are currently using.

If you want to mount the root of that installation, you can try a command such as:

```
# mount /dev/VolGroup/lv_root /mnt
```

If you also want to mount the home volume, follow that with:

```
# mount /dev/VolGroup/lv_home /mnt/home
```

And assuming `sda1` is indeed meant for the boot partition:

```
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
```

I hope that helps you understand what is going on with your second disk!